# How to play mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) in jwplayer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video, jwplayer6, video-codecs

I am using jwplayer in my rails3 app. It is playing all normal mp4 and flash videos properly.

But I observed that it is not able to play:

> mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile)

When I parsed that video with stremio it gives the following details.

```
#<FFMPEG::Movie:0x00000001f17240 @path="/home/pinki/Videos/QuickTime_test9_2m4s_MPEG4ASP_CBR_512kbps_640x480_24fps_AAC-LCv4_CBR_320kbps_Stereo_48000Hz.mp4", @container="mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2", @duration=124.05, @time=0.0, @creation_time=2009-05-26 16:17:45 +0530, @bitrate=1648, @rotation=nil, @video_stream="mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 491 kb/s, 24.04 fps, 24.04 tbr, 2500 tbn, 1k tbc", @audio_stream="aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 315 kb/s", @video_codec="mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile)", @colorspace="yuv420p", @video_bitrate=491, @resolution="640x480", @dar="4:3", @audio_codec="aac", @audio_channels="stereo", @audio_bitrate=315, @audio_sample_rate=48000>
```

How can I play this videos.

I am using jwplayer-rails gem and Current version of JW Player is 6.2.3115